# unable to start webrick in windows xp

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows-xp, mongrel, webrick

i got this error while i try to start the webrick server on my windows xp.

```
←[31mCould not find eventmachine-0.12.10 in any of the sources←[0m
←[33mRun `bundle install` to install missing gems.←[0m
```

I've already did a 'bundle install'. Also tried to install mongrel but it's not helping!

Gemfile codes:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.0.10'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

#gem 'sqlite3'

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end
group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

gem 'thin'

# Use unicorn as the web server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger (ruby-debug for Ruby 1.8.7+, ruby-debug19 for Ruby 1.9.2+)
# gem 'ruby-debug'
# gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => 'ruby-debug'

# Bundle the extra gems:
# gem 'bj'
# gem 'nokogiri'
# gem 'sqlite3-ruby', :require => 'sqlite3'
# gem 'aws-s3', :require => 'aws/s3'

# Bundle gems for the local environment. Make sure to
# put test-only gems in this group so their generators
# and rake tasks are available in development mode:
# group :development, :test do
#   gem 'webrat'
# end
```

Comment: did you try `bundle exec rails s` ?

Comment: Hi @Bohdan Pohorilets, i got the following error message when i tried "bundle exec rails s"

- "Could not find eventmachine-0.12.10 in any of the sources"

Comment: Hi @BohdanPohorilets, i've posted the codes for my gem file above. My apologies for the late reply. Thank you for your help so far.

Comment: Thin depends on eventmachine so if you run `bundle install` it should be installed Did you try to delete your `Gemfile.lock` and run `bundle install` again?

Comment: hi @Bohdan here's what i got when i did that--------- ←[31mCould not find gem 'rails (= 3.0.10)' in any of the gem sources listed in
our Gemfile.←[0m
←[33mRun `bundle install` to install missing gems.←[0m

any idea why it's happening?

Comment: and when you execute `gem install rails -v 3.0.10` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running these commands and then try `rails s` again.

```
gem install specific_install
gem specific_install -l http://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine.git
```

Comment: Hi @Nexerus, i got the same error message as i've first posted even though eventmachine was successfully install. Any idea why? thank you so far.

Comment: Try checking out the specific version from the Git repository and trying again, not quite sure on the command to install from a directory but try `gem specific_install ./` if that doesn't work try with `-l ./`